# Sessão PHP após Load()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Estou enfrentando um pequeno problema em relação a minha sessão..

Quando recarrego a pagina pela função `load()`, minha sessão não atualiza e é exibida a mensagem

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION
```

Pelo que entendi, ao utilizar o `load()`, os dados da sessão são perdidos.

Há alguma forma de resolver este problema?

```
 $(".editoraview h1").click(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'classes/consulta.php',
          success : function(txt){
            $('#view-full').load('classes/consulta.php');
          },
          error: function(result) {
            alert("Erro");
          }
        });
    });
```

Obrigado =D

Answer (score 4):

No php você precisa iniciar uma nova sessão antes de usar variáveis de sessão, para isso chame:

```
session_start();
```

Antes de usar `$_SESSION`.

Se esse não for o caso então edite a pergunta colocando o código do arquivo php para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

basta dar um `<?php session_start()?>` na página que está sendo carregada pelo `load()`